# Error while running berks install

Tags: windows, ssl, docker, chef-infra, berkshelf

I have a windows instance which on top of that I'm running a windows docker container. On the instance itself I'm succeed to execute `berks vendor/install` without any issues. However on a windows docker container running on that machine it doesn't work and throws me a timeout error.
The error wasn't clear enough so I decided to execute `librarian-chef install` and got some more output. It appears that there is something related to SSL connection.
I tried several things after a long research during last couple days but still getting same error.

`Resolving cookbook dependencies...
Fetching 'firefox' from source at .
Fetching 'firefox_test' from source at test/fixtures/cookbooks/firefox_test
Fetching cookbook index from https://supermarket.chef.io...
[2017-08-02T09:09:19+00:00] ERROR: Timeout connecting to https://supermarket.chef.io/universe, retry 1/5
[2017-08-02T09:14:24+00:00] ERROR: Timeout connecting to https://supermarket.chef.io/universe, retry 2/5
[2017-08-02T09:19:29+00:00] ERROR: Timeout connecting to https://supermarket.chef.io/universe, retry 3/5
[2017-08-02T09:24:34+00:00] ERROR: Timeout connecting to https://supermarket.chef.io/universe, retry 4/5
[2017-08-02T09:29:39+00:00] ERROR: Timeout connecting to https://supermarket.chef.io/universe, retry 5/5
Error retrieving universe from source: https://supermarket.chef.io
  * [Berkshelf::APIClient::TimeoutError] Unable to connect to: universe
Using firefox (4.0.0) from source at .
Using firefox_test (0.1.0) from source at test/fixtures/cookbooks/firefox_test
Cookbook 'dmg' (4.0.0) not found in any of the sources! This can happen if the remote cookbook has been deleted or if the sources inside the Berksfile have changed Please run berks update dmg to resolve to a valid version.`

I would be grateful if anyone could assist here.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include the actual error message. Also you would not generally be using both Berks and Librarian at the same time, so that may be a red herring.

Comment: I'm not using Berks and Librarian at same time, as I explained Berks logs weren't clear enough so I ran librarian-chef to see if I can get an advanced error logs and I got. Berks and Librarian are different tools but at the end they receiving the same (connect to supermarket or anywhere and downloading desired cookbooks).

Comment: They use totally unrelated config files (Berksfile vs Cheffile) so you can't just run one or the other.

Comment: I know that, and if you have those both files you can run berks and librarian.
Anyway, the point is not about berks and librarian but connection problem.
I took firefox cookbook for example, here what I got from running berks:

Comment: Error retrieving universe from source: https://supermarket.chef.io
  * [Berkshelf::APIClient::TimeoutError] Unable to connect to: universe

Comment: Please put the _full error_ in the question.

Comment: You have some corporate firewall?

Comment: I'm running on Google Cloud, the firewall on the machine is disabled and in any way I have made any any rules in Google Cloud dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error; this only happens when I am logged into my company's network. When I am on the internet directly, there is no issue; so I suspect it is a problem with a proxy server, or something in my company's network.

Slava: I sincerely hope that this is the same kind of problem; I just did not want to duplicate the question; please let me know and I can create a different item.

When I get this problem, the error message is:

```
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>>>>>> Message: 1 actions failed.
>>>>>>     Failed to complete #converge action: [Error connecting to https://supermarket.chef.io/universe - Failed to open TCP connection to supermarket.chef.io:443 (getaddrinfo: No address associated with hostname)] on default-centos-67
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration
```

in my case, the web proxy needed to be set properly.

Comment: Carlos, thanks for sharing but unfortunately it doesn't work for me from anywhere.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, Slava. One question: what exactly are you doing to get this error? Are you logging into the container and running 'berks vendor/install' directly on a command line in it?

Comment: Also: did you not get more information after the messages you shared in the initial question? In my case, I got the "Exception" that indicated that the issue was a DNS issue, which helped me explore further. The messages you provided seem to be caused by a deeper issue. In the case of the errors you are getting, my limited experience have always had an SSL configuration issue behind them.

Comment: No I don't get any further information, however I have tried to run librarian-chef install instead just to see if I'm getting any additional information and indeed I have got same error with some more SSL errors, so like you are right it's related to SSL but I can't figure out how to fix.